# Convert custom data type &/ calculating duration in R

Tags: r, transformation, data-conversion, calculation

I have downloaded reports from a specific tool that use the custom data format `##d:##h:##m:##s` (days:hours:minutes:seconds). It gets imported to R as a factor/ string. How to I convert it to duration. It is not so much about data type but the calculation. The data frame is 367x58. All 367 elements do not have the same time (most in hours, minutes and seconds; few range in days).

Input:

```
> # Converting Date/Time
```

> dput(head(AS_1.2$Open_for))
>   structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
>   NA_integer_, NA_integer_), .Label = c("01d:07h:45m:55s", "01d:11h:02m:36s", 
>   "01d:23h:26m:01s", "01m:07s", "01m:10s", "01m:12s", "01m:15s", 
>   "01m:23s", "01m:27s", "01m:32s", "01m:42s", "01m:43s", "01m:44s", 
>   "01m:45s", "02d:21h:14m:52s", "02h:06m:37s", "02h:09m:35s", "02h:25m:34s", 
>   "02h:51m:50s", "02m:04s", "02m:09s", "02m:18s", "02m:44s", "02s", 
>   "03d:05h:29m:14s", "03d:09h:16m:32s", "03h:41m:59s", "03h:43m:19s", 
>   "03m:08s", "03m:12s", "03m:21s", "03m:23s", "03m:24s", "03m:28s", 
>   "03m:33s", "03m:38s", "03m:44s", "03m:46s", "03m:48s", "03m:53s", 
>   "03m:57s", "03s", "04d:01m:53s", "04d:07h:40m:40s", "04d:19h:31m:30s", 
>   "04h:23m:45s", "04m:03s", "04m:09s", "04m:16s", "04s", "05d:22h:59m:24s", 
>   "05d:23h:18m:25s", "05m:27s", "05m:36s", "05m:38s", "05m:41s", 
>   "05s", "06d:12h:38m:51s", "06d:12h:46m:17s", "06d:12h:53m:11s", 
>   "06d:13h:03m:29s", "06d:13h:15m:29s", "06d:13h:46m:12s", "06m:09s", 
>   "06m:30s", "06s", "07d:03h:09m:39s", "07d:19h:08m:31s", "07s", 
>   "08s", "09m", "09m:29s", "09m:39s", "11m:44s", "11s", "12d:23h:04m:24s", 
>   "13s", "14s", "17s", "18m:46s", "18s", "19h", "20h:19m:39s", 
>   "20m:33s", "20m:49s", "20s", "21m:17s", "21s", "22m:06s", "25s", 
>   "26s", "27m:22s", "38s", "39s", "45s", "46s", "50s", "51m:23s"
>   ), class = "factor")
>   ?dput()

Expected Output (in hours):

For first element => 01d:07h:45m:55s = 175.7653 hours

Comment: It will be easier for people to help you id you can include in the body of your question the output of `dput(head(AS_1.2$Open_for))`, which includes the underlying data type (looks like a factor here), not just the way the data displays. It would be even better if you could include in that sample some different formats.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your response. I have made the suggested changes. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lubridate` library can help with this if we just format the data a bit. `lubridate` expects upper case "H", "M", "S" for hour, minute, and seconds; a lower case  "m" is interpreted as a month.

So we can do

```
library(lubridate)
x <- c("01d:07h:45m:55s", "01d:11h:02m:36s", "01d:23h:26m:01s", "01m:07s")
cleaned <- gsub("([hms])", "\\U\\1", x, perl=TRUE) # upper case the h, m and s
duration(cleaned)
# [1] "114355s (~1.32 days)" "126156s (~1.46 days)" "170761s (~1.98 days)"
# [4] "67s (~1.12 minutes)" 
as.numeric(duration(cleaned), units="hours")
# [1] 31.76527778 35.04333333 47.43361111  0.01861111
```

Comment: Hi MrFlick, the output for this if NA.                                                                                          
Input:  
# Duration
install.packages("lubridate")
library("lubridate")

x <- c(AS_1.2$Open_for)

cleaned <- gsub("([hms])", "\\U\\1", x, perl=TRUE) # upper case the h, m and s
duration(cleaned)

z <- as.numeric(duration(cleaned), units="hours")

Output: > str(z)
 num [1:367] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
> summary(z)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
     NA      NA      NA     NaN      NA      NA     367

Comment: Additionally, after the gsub is where it goes from having numeric entries to completely NA.

Comment: Try `x <- as.character(AS_1.2$Open_for)`. Your data seems to be read as a factor rather than a character vector.

Comment: Yes! It worked. z
  [1]           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
  [9]           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
 [17]           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
 [25]           NA 5.638889e-02           NA 5.638889e-02           NA           NA 9.333333e-02 6.222222e-02. *IT"S SO BEAUTIFUL!!* Thank you very much MrFlick!

Comment: I tried the same again as the data sheet updated. The output after running the code block above is x, cleaned are all NULL. No error message.